# Fill a portion of a list in Python / Equivalent of std::fill

Tags: python, list, numpy

I was just wondering if there is a clean solution in python to filling a portion of a list with some value (apart from simply iterating over the sublist). E.g., in C++ I would use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill). So far, I found the following syntax:

```
x = [0]*10       # some array
x[2:5] = [7]*3
```

A solution using numpy would be fine as well.

Comment: Same approach works for numpy as well, Have you tried with numpy ?

Comment: Yes it works, but I'm not fully satisfied with that answer. Perhaps I should have clarified my goal. When I look at this code-snippet, I need a moment to grasp what is going on. Opposed to that, `std::fill(fist, last, value)` is a lot clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: hava a look at, [`numpy.put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) which is roughly equivalent to above.

Comment: you can define your own short `fill` function that does this in a loop or using your own solution quite easily...

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Yeah, sure, but I don't want to start maintaining my own little helper library

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.repeat(0, 10)
x[2:5] = np.repeat(7, 3)
```

Comment: For numpy you don't need the repeat.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not substantially different from the example within the question

Comment: Slice assignment can change the length of a list.  The size of the array is fixed.  The scalar value is broadcasted to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Each class has its own methods.  For numpy`

```
x = np.zeros(10, int)
```

makes an array of zeros.

```
x[2:7] = 3
```

assigns 3 to a portion of it.

That's similar to your list example, but critically different in some ways.  List slice assignment is different from numpy's.